# We assume that we have given a following function

Tags: c++

We assume that we have given a following function:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass(double var) {
        this->var = var;
    }
protected:
    double var;
};

MyClass foo( MyClass1 obj) {
}
```

In function `foo()` We would like get access to `obj.var`. But how?
We can't use keyword `double` again so we can't create getter `getVar()`
More over, we can't make our function `foo()` as friend of `MyClass`
Additionally, `foo()` can't be a method.

Comment: Why do you keep ruling out possible solutions? The keyword `double` can be used as many times as you like. Use it. C++ supports friend functions. Use them.

Comment: Ok. First of all answer the question of @juanchopanza and then also tell us, why do you add non-existing restrictions to the language?

Answer (score 1):

Makr `MyClass1` a sub-class of `MyClass` and provide public access to `MyClass::var` via a member function:

```
MyClass1 : public MyClass
{
 public:
  auto v()->decltype((var)) // returns a reference to var
  { 
    return var; 
  }
};
```

Then

```
MyClass foo( MyClass1 obj) {
  obj.v()++; // increments var
  return obj;
}
```

Note that this requires that the `MyClass::MyClass(double)` constructor be non-private.

Another alternative is to make `var` public in the derived class. But if you find yourself doing this in real code you have to stop and ask yourself a few questions:

```
MyClass1 : public MyClass
{
 public:
  using MyClass::var; // look! var is now public
};

MyClass foo( MyClass1 obj) {
  obj.var++; // increments var
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: @RaymondChen That's right. I assumed it was a typo.

Comment: It also uses the keyword `double`.

Comment: @BartvanNierop Fixed (probably, not tested.)

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo It seems like some kind of pointless code challenge.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I needed a crap answer to a crap question to push me past 100K points in style :-)

Comment: So `juanchopanza` == `user3466525`?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo No need to be offensive! I was joking, but SO is a good source of bad questions. Choose a question at random, and it is likely to be poor.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access protected members of a class from outside of the class or any derived objects.
If you cannot alter `MyClass` directly but want to access a `protected` value you can inherit from it using another type where you define a getter.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass(double var) : member_var(var) {}
protected:
  double member_var;
};
class OtherClass : public MyClass
{
public:
  OtherClass(double var) : MyClass(var) {}
  double get_member(void) const { return member_var;  }
};
```

You can use the derived class for `foo`.

```
OtherClass foo(OtherClass obj)
{
  double x = 5.0 + obj.get_member();
}
```